# Server/Client based with pipe (not FIFO) file permission checker C++

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, client-server

I need to create a Client/Server program with pipe (not FIFO) where user inputs the filename and an octal permission and the server returns "YES" if the octal file permission is the same as the input  and "NO" otherwise.

I've created 2 pipes one for file_name and one for octal. I don't know how to verify the property of the file inside C++. It is my first pipe program that I've made so I think I could have a lot of errors. Thanks for your support!

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() 
{ 
    // We use two pipes 
    // First pipe to send input string from parent 
    // Second pipe to send concatenated string from child 

    int fd1[2];  // Used to store two ends of first pipe 
    int fd2[2];  // Used to store two ends of second pipe 

    char octal[7]; 
    char input_str[100]; 

    pid_t p; 

    if (pipe(fd1)==-1) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" ); 
        return 1; 
    } 
    if (pipe(fd2)==-1) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" ); 
        return 1; 
    } 

    scanf("%s", input_str); 
    scanf("%d", octal);
    p = fork(); 

    if (p < 0) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "fork Failed" ); 
        return 1; 
    } 

    // Parent process 
    else if (p > 0) 
    { 
        char answear[100]; 

        close(fd1[0]);  // Close reading end of first pipe 

        // Write input string and close writing end of first 
        // pipe. 
        write(fd1[1], input_str, strlen(input_str)+1); 
    write(fd2[1], octal, 7); 
    close(fd2[1]);
        close(fd1[1]); 

        // Wait for child to send a string 
        wait(NULL); 

        // Read string from child, print it and close 
        // reading end. 
        read(fd2[0], answear, 100); 
        printf("The answear is %s\n", answear); 
        close(fd2[0]); 
    } 

    // child process 
    else
    { 
        close(fd1[1]);  // Close writing end of first pipe 
    close(fd2[1]);  // Close writing end of secound pipe
        // Read a string using first pipe 
        char file_name[100]; 
        read(fd1[0], file_name, 100); 
    // Read a int using secound pipe 
    int octal2[7];
    read(fd2[0], octal2, 7);

        // verify the octal permission of the file and give the result on the answear
        struct stat buf;  
    stat(file_name, &buf);
    int statchmod = buf.st_mode & (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
    if (statchmod == octal2[0])
        char answear[]="Totul e OK!"; //OK
    else
        chmod(file_name, S_IRWXU);
        char answear[]="Drepturile au fost modificate"; //not OK
        // Close both reading ends 
        close(fd1[0]); 
        close(fd2[0]); 


        // Write concatenated string and close writing end 
        write(fd2[1], answear, 100); 
        close(fd2[1]); 

        exit(0); 
    } 
}
```

Now the result doesn't show if it changed something. It shows just "The result is   ".

Comment: I think `stat()` is the function you are looking for --- it can give you information about a specified file.  In particular, have a look at the `st_mode` member of the `struct stat` that it writes to:  https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: That code looks more like C than C++.  However, if you're using C++, so be it.  I'd rather you tagged with one language than both.

Comment: The child should only close one of the write ends of the pipes up front.  It should close the read end of the pipe it will use to write to the server; it should close the write end of the pipe it will use to read from the server.  After reading the file name from the server, it can close the read end of the pipe.  After writing the response to the server, it can close the write end of the pipe — or, at a pinch, just exit since that will close it too.

Comment: You also have problems with the parent writing on both of the pipes; that is going to confuse things. You have two pipes: `fd1` and `fd2`. The parent should write on `fd1[1]` and read on `fd2[0]`; conversely, the child should read on `fd1[0]` and write on `fd2[1]`. Each should close the unused ends of the pipes, do their work, and close the used ends of the pipes when appropriate. With single-cycle programs — with a single message in each direction — you can be sloppier about closing pipe descriptors. When the code needs to detect EOF, you must be more careful. You should check return values.